# Finding derivatives of a 3-linear symetric operator

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Let $T \in \mathcal{L_3}(\mathbb {R^3},\mathbb {R^n})$ symetric

> ($T(u,v,w)=T(v,u,w)=T(u,w,v)$)

then how can i find $D^kT(0)$? I have been struggling with it and i know they are all null except for $k=3$ but i can't show that $\dfrac{||T(x)||}{||x||} \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$.

Edit: I've got an ideia but don't know If is correct.

$||T(x_1,x_2,x_3)||\leq||T|| |x_1||x_2||x_3|$
So $\dfrac{||T(x)||}{||x||}\leq\dfrac{||T|| |x_1||x_2||x_3|}{||x||}$

Taking the sum norm and using the fact that $\dfrac{|x_i|}{|x_1|+...+|x_n|}\leq 1$ then the limit goes to 0.

But this is for $DT(0)$ only

Edit 2:

For $DT(x)$, taking the directional derivative and using linearity i can show that $DT(x)y=T(y_1,x_2,x_3)+T(x_1,y_2,x_3)+T(x_1,x_2,y_3)$ i guess with that i can work on It.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by $\mathcal{L}_3(\Bbb R^3, \Bbb R^n)$?

Comment: 3-linear, its linear in all entries

Comment: So do you mean $T(x,y,z)$ linear in $x,y,z$ with $x,y,z$ in $\mathbb R$ or each in $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: @Hyperplane each in $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f\colon \mathbb R^3 \to\mathbb R$ is linear in each component, then $f$ is of the form $f(x,y,z)=\alpha xyz$. Hence $T(x,y,z) = xyz {\bf v}$ for some ${\bf v} \in\mathbb R^n$ (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_map)

So $DT = (yz{\bf v}, xz{\bf v}, yz{\bf v})={\bf v}(yz, xz, xy)$

And the second and third derivative are

$D^2T = {\bf v} \otimes \begin{pmatrix} 0&z&y\\z&0&x \\ y&x & 0    \end{pmatrix}$

$D^3T = const. N\times 3\times 3\times 3$ tensor

$D^kT =0$ $(N\times 3^k)$ tensor for $k>3$

Comment: I'm really not familiarized with tensors but Will check It out